# How to set timezone inside a postgres function

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(userid BIGINT)
  RETURNS REAL
  SECURITY DEFINER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  ------------------------Fetch all Active Games for a user and add it to one cursor--------------------------------------
    PersonGames NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR select timezonename from user where id=userid;
BEGIN
  OPEN PersonGames;
  LOOP

    FETCH PersonGames INTO PersonGame;
    IF NOT found
    THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
    SET TIMEZONE=PersonGame.timezonename;
  --  execute 'set TIMEZONE=$1' using PersonGame.timezonename;
end loop;
END;
$$;
```

I am getting error invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "timezonename"

even i tried to change code execute 'set TIMEZONE=$1' using PersonGame.timezonename;

But this is also not working.

I want to set timezone inside my function.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why do you want to change Postgres DB timezone? This setting applies to entire DB. 2. The syntax is `SET TIME ZONE value` ( [see documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html#AEN75747) ).

Comment: I have one requirement, which requires user wise.I already tried but not working.

Comment: @KristoMägi: changing the time zone through `set` does not apply to "the entire DB" - only to the current session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways:

1. You can use the [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) command, with a fully-constructed string (i.e.: without `USING`<sup>1</sup>), and use the [`SET [LOCAL] TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) statement, as you were doing in your function.

   This function will let you test it:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_set_time_zone(_new_time_zone TEXT)
      RETURNS TEXT
      SECURITY DEFINER
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS $$
   BEGIN
       EXECUTE 'SET LOCAL TIME ZONE ''' || _new_time_zone || ''';' ;
       RETURN current_setting('timezone')  ;
   END;
   $$;
   ```

   You can check it with:

   ```
   SELECT test_set_time_zone('Europe/Paris');
   ```

   ```
   | test_set_time_zone |
   | :----------------- |
   | Europe/Paris       |
   ```
2. You can use the [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) function in a similar fashion, being called via [`PERFORM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT), setting `'timezone'` as the parameter to configure, and deciding whether to make the setting `local` or `global`.

   You can check it with:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_set_time_zone_2 (_new_time_zone TEXT)
      RETURNS TEXT
      SECURITY DEFINER
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS $$
   BEGIN
       PERFORM set_config('timezone', _new_time_zone, true /* local */) ;
       RETURN current_setting('timezone')  ;
   END;
   $$;

   SELECT test_set_time_zone_2('US/Central') ;
   ```

   ```
   | test_set_time_zone_2 |
   | :------------------- |
   | US/Central           |
   ```

You can check both functions at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=61d610e291aff25abadba03fd201b94e)*  I didn't try any global setting, because my guess is that in this platform a web user won't have the proper privileges; my best guess is that you can do the changes global in you system doing equivalent things.

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>As per comment from **Pavel Stehule**: `USING` clause is available for execution plan parameters only. `SET` has not execution plan - and then the `USING` clause is not available.</sub>

Comment: `USING` clause is available for execution plan parameters only. `SET` has not execution plan - and then the `USING` clause is not available.

Comment: Yes second part works using 
 PERFORM 'SET TIME ZONE '||TimezoneName;

Comment: Why does postgres require a string literal here?

Comment: The first solution with `EXECUTE` seems extraordinarily vulnerable to SQL injection.